# How to append a set of numpy arrays while inside a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

The thing I want to do is, I want append a set of numpy arrays one after the other while in a for loop. So whenever a new array comes, the new array will be appended to the older one. The code I have written is as follows:

```
def joinArray(highest_score, seq):

      seq1 = np.array([])
      seq2 = np.array([])
      seq3 = np.array([])
      seq4 = np.array([])
      seq5 = np.array([])

      if(highest_score == 1):
    
            seq1 = np.concatenate((seq1,seq), axis = 1)
    
            return(seq1)

      if(highest_score == 2):
    
            seq2 = np.concatenate((seq2,seq), axis = 1)

      if(highest_score == 3):
    
            seq3 = np.concatenate((seq3,seq), axis = 1)

      if(highest_score == 4):
    
            seq4 = np.concatenate((seq4,seq), axis = 1)

      if(highest_score == 5):
    
            seq5 = np.concatenate((seq5,seq), axis = 1)

def sequenced(dat):

      for i in range(0,10):
    
          passvalue = joinArray(highest_index[i]+1,dat)



for i in range(0,38,2):

       H = Data2.iloc[:, i:i+2]
       H = H.dropna()

       scaler = StandardScaler()
       Sdatad1 = scaler.fit_transform(H)

h1 = sequenced(Sdatad1)
```

However, on running this code, I get this error:

```
   AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I have tried np.append(), np.vstack() also but all end up in errors. Is there a way this problem can be solved?

Comment: Why aren't you using lists?

Comment: `np.concatenate` requires careful attention to argument shapes.  What the shape of `seq1`, or `seq`?  `axis=1` requires at least 2 dimensions.  You can append elements to a list without much thought as to the contents, since it just adds a reference in-place.  `concatenate` (and derivatives) makes a whole new array, and must align shapes just right.  It's making a multidimensional array, not just taking on a reference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are redefining your arrays each run. I used a little trick with global keyword here, but you can easily convert the code into OOP, if you are familiar with it.
Secondly, in order for python to append array to array (and not number after number), you have to define your array as 1- dimension array. I simplified your joinArray function, but you should be able to continue working with it.

```
import numpy as np

highest_score_HMM = 1

seq1 = np.empty((0, 1))
seq2 = np.empty((0, 1))
seq3 = np.empty((0, 1))
seq4 = np.empty((0, 1))
seq5 = np.empty((0, 1))


def joinArray(highest_score, seq):

    global seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, seq5

    if(highest_score == 1):
        seq1 = np.concatenate((seq1, seq))

    if(highest_score_HMM == 2):
        seq2 = np.concatenate(seq2, seq)

    if(highest_score_HMM == 3):
        seq3 = np.concatenate(seq3, seq)

    if(highest_score_HMM == 4):
        seq4 = np.concatenate(seq4, seq)

    if(highest_score_HMM == 5):
        seq5 = np.concatenate(seq5, seq)


seq = np.array([[2]])
joinArray(1, seq)
joinArray(1, seq)
joinArray(1, seq)

print(seq1)
```

result: [[2.][2.][2.]]

result[0]: [2.]

Comment: Thanks! Its working but unfortunately as my arrays have different dimensions, appending them gives an error.

Comment: Repeated `concatenate` is slower than list append, and requires careful attention to the array shape, both as initialed and in the loop.  Each `concatenate` makes a whole new array, with all the implied copying.